# How can I Insert Into Table using both of Values and Select of other table?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to `Insert` many data In my table using both of `Values` keyword and `select` of other table like:

```
INSERT INTO ProductGroupTypeTranslation(CreationTime, Title, CoreId, Language)
VALUES (GETDATE())
SELECT PersianName, Id, EnName FROM ProductGroupTypeAsName
```

Is it possible? Or is my query true?

If no, how can I do it?

Attention that some of my data which I want to insert is note in another table that I can get them and insert, I have to set them using `Values` keyword.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simply:

```
INSERT INTO ProductGroupTypeTranslation(CreationTime, Title, CoreId, Language)
    SELECT
        GETDATE(), PersianName, Id, EnName 
    FROM
        ProductGroupTypeAsNam;
```

If you want to insert just some data from `ProductGroupTypeAsNam` you should use `WHERE`

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
INSERT INTO ProductGroupTypeTranslation(CreationTime, Title, CoreId, Language)
    SELECT
        GETDATE(), PersianName, Id, EnName 
    FROM
        ProductGroupTypeAsName
```

or, if you need the same value of date for all rows inserted

```
DECLARE @now datetime = GETDATE();

INSERT INTO ProductGroupTypeTranslation(CreationTime, Title, CoreId, Language)
    SELECT
        @now, PersianName, Id, EnName 
    FROM
        ProductGroupTypeAsName
```

Answer (score 1):

This could be done using the following:

```
INSERT INTO ProductGroupTypeTranslation(CreationTime, Title, CoreId, Language)
    SELECT
        GETDATE(), PersianName, Id, EnName 
    FROM
        ProductGroupTypeAsName;
```

I.e. you embed the values into the select statement it's like you're projecting.